# Get type from compiled view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I currently have code that compiles a mvc view to get the type from the view.

```
var compiledViewType = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(path);
var baseType = compiledViewType.BaseType;

// Check to see if the view has been found and that it is a generic type
if (baseType == null || !baseType.IsGenericType)
{
    return null;
}
```

The issue I have now, is some views are precompiled and do not have a path. Is there a way for me to get the precompiled view from the dll, by path. So I can get the type from it.